# I need to display XML in jquery parsed from a PHP file

Tags: php, jquery

Here is the Parser in PHP it currently displays in PHP and I need a function to display the parsed images in jQuery.

```
for($y = 0; $y <= 1; $y++){
    $featured_channel = array_values($featured_channel);
    $arraytotal = (count($featured_channel)-1);
    $x = rand(0,$arraytotal);

I want to pull $featured_channel[$x]-> into jQuery and display the images in that.
```

Comment: You'll need to tell us what kind of values `$featured_channel` holds.  Are they image src URL's?  Image blobs?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry...They are images from an XML file with a URL path, a description, and a title for it.

Answer (score 0):

Have the PHP file output whatever information you want to display on your page and then use an ajax call to grab that information from the PHP file into a javascript function:

----JavaScript----

```
function get_data() {
    $.get('path_to_script.php', function (data) {
        $('#some_container_element').html(data);
    });
}
```

NOTE: this function expects the PHP file to have formatted the output to be directly added to the webpage, something like:

----PHP Output----

```
>>Title Here<<
<img src="http://website.com/image.jpg" />
<br>
>>Description Here<<
```

Comment: Really it boils down to how do I display this PHP variable in    jQuery.$featured_channel[$x]->

Comment: Have the PHP script output the html code that should be displayed via jquery. echo $featured_channel[$x]['title']." <img src='" . $featured_channel[$x]['src'] . "'> " . $featured_channel[$x]['description'];